# How / is it possible to extract polygons from raster (ex: crop boundaries from satellite imagery)?

Tags: raster, vector, feature-extraction

Is there any librairies/tools/others that can extract polygons out of crop boundaries from a satellite imagery. On the example below (random location in Belgium), the various fields limits are very easy to spot for a human - are any tool able to get those polygons out (bonus if in Python, but not blocking).

I feel this should be doable, but did not find anything out of a quite thorough google search. This feels similar to techniques used by Photoshop and other to extract subjects from images.

[image: crops]

Comment: What is the input format of your image? Is it a GeoTIFF, a paper map or just a print screen from Google Maps?

Comment: @Taras pretty much what's the best - somethig that works out of geotiles would be best, but tiff are clearly an option if it makes the extraction easier/better

Comment: The task is not as easy as it may feel. One much used and expensive tool is https://www.gim.be/en/products/gis-software-1/ecognition. I am not sure if this free alternative still works https://docs.sigro.org/qgis-basic-training/en/classification.html. Probably all EU countries are performing that task for controlling farmer subsidies. You may find articles about those campaigns with keywords like LPIS, area based subsidies, monitoring,